# NewtonSoft JSON not raising Exception when using MissingMemberHandling.Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, exception, jsonconverter

We use the Newtonsoft Json converter to deserialise API requests. As we don't want to receive data/members which are not part of the request class in the BackEnd, we set `SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling` to `MissingMemberHandling.Error`:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(a =>
    {
        a.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
    }
```

But instead of receiving an Exception, we end up with a 'null' request object for the API-call:
[image]

Why don't we get an Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: my controller was configurered like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController
{
}
```

Since everything was working as expected before we added the missing member setting, I did not think of the missing attribute `[ApiController]`. Adding this, made this controller act like the others regarding the Json serialisation!

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]  // <- added this
public class MyController
{
}
```

To be sure this isn’t forgotten, we wrote a test which checks all controller classes for this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you configured Newtonsoft.Json. I make a working example. Here is the steps.

1. Add the following Nuget package.

   `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`
2. Configure it in `Startup.cs`.

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(option=>
            {
                option.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
            });
    }
   ```
3. Add a request action and the model. This is the all controller code.

   ```
   [ApiController]
   [Route("[controller]")]
   public class ValController:Controller
   {
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult LoginAsync([FromBody]Login login)
    {
        return Ok(login);
    }
   }
   public class Login
   {
    public string comm { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Then I access the action.

[image]

Comment: This is what I already did - but I digged a bit more into this and it seems the problem only occurs wich one API-controler.
One note - that API-controle allows anonymous API-call, while the others don't.
But yours here also allows anonymous calls...

Comment: Yes, I added the `[ApiController]`. This is the all code.

Comment: Thanks Karney. I’ve upvoted your post as it gives a nice full source and full functionality demo of what I was aspecting, but the actual problem lies in the fact of the missing [ApiController] attribute. So therefor I’ll be checking my own answer as the actual answer to my question.